# How can I make an imageView sticks to another one if it's near the other one in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an image view to stick to another in the when I run my project. I've done Drag and Drop, but that would only make the ImageView move. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: add some code, what you have done so far, that will help us understand. Here  read how to ask a question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont understand the question well,
if you can add some pictures to explain more or code.
i think translation can help you:-

```
imageview.setTranslationY(-50);
```

**result**
[image: description]
or:

```
imageview.setY(-50);
```

but remember, **setY** change the real position, and **setTranslationY** change the position based on its first position (position = position + translation).

Comment: Well, it's kinda like in the image "before", it has 2 imageviews and I want the upper one to make the lower one stick to it when it is near.

Comment: you can calculate images position and do what you want using getX() getY(), add some codes to explain your question, i dont understand you well